# Error parsing time with two decimal digits in Java 17, but succeeds in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, java-17

The following code snippet runs without error in Java 8.  However, when I run the same code in Java 17 it fails.

```java
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH[:mm[:ss[.SSS]]]X");
        OffsetDateTime offSetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-09T08:59:00.00Z", formatter);
        System.out.println(offSetDateTime);
    }
}
```

Output when run on Java 17:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-10-09T08:59:00.00Z' could not be parsed at index 19
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:404)
    at Main2.main(Main2.java:9)
```

However, if I run the same code against Java 8 it gives the following result:

```
2021-10-09T08:59Z
```

If I change the test data from `"2021-10-09T08:59:00.00Z"` to `"2021-10-09T08:59:00.000Z"`, it works in Java 17.  Any idea what changes in Java 17 has causes it it fail?

Comment: Looks like a more strict check. If you remove one of `S` it works for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This behaviour seems to be caused by the fix for [JDK-8230136](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8230136).

JDK-8230136 is the issue that the fraction-of-second field does not check its minimum width. If you do `appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 3, 3, false)` in a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, 1, 2, or 3 digits will all be accepted by that field.

`DateTimeFormatter` uses `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` under the hood, and so it is also affected. The `SSS` in your pattern eventually leads to a call like `appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 3, 3, false)` on a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

If you need the old behaviour, you can call `appendFraction` with your own minimum digit count.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH[:mm[:ss[")
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 1, 3, true)
        .appendPattern("]]]X")
        .toFormatter();
```

Comment: A relevant spec quote that was fixed by that issue: "When parsing in strict mode, the number of parsed digits must be between the minimum and maximum width."

Comment: @M.Justin Yeah, I saw that too, but didn't manage to find which page that quote is from. I thought it was from [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), but I didn't find it there.

Comment: The quote's from [DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendFraction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendFraction(java.time.temporal.TemporalField,int,int,boolean)).